# Bubble sort descending list in Python

Tags: python, sorting, bubble-sort

How can I arrange a list, with bubble sort, but in descending order?
I searched in other topics, but I couldn't find an answer.
This is my working implementation of Bubblesort code:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import resource
start = timer()
def bubbleSort(alist):
    for passnum in range(len(alist)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(passnum):
            if alist[i]>alist[i+1]:
                temp = alist[i]
                alist[i] = alist[i+1]
                alist[i+1] = temp


with open('lista.txt', 'r') as f:
    long_string = f.readline()
    alist = long_string.split(',')
bubbleSort(alist)
f = open("bubble.txt", "w")
print >>f,(alist)
print resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss / 1000
end = timer()
print(end - start)
f.close()
```

Comment: assuming the bubbleSort is working, I think changing `if alist[i]>alist[i+1]` to `if alist[i+1] > alist[i]` should work.

Comment: What does your code do? Does it work? If not, how do you know? What's the smallest amount of data it fails with? Is there any data it works with? See [ask], particularly how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the greater than in the following if statement `if alist[i]<alist[i+1]:` with a smaller than `if alist[i]<alist[i+1]:`. You also need to return alist leaving you with the following.

```
def bubbleSort(alist):
for passnum in range(len(alist)-1,0,-1):
    for i in range(passnum):
        if alist[i]<alist[i+1]:
            temp = alist[i]
            alist[i] = alist[i+1]
            alist[i+1] = temp
return(alist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Write like this `alist[i]<alist[i+1]`

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions for reverse bubble sort.

solution1: Here j travels from right to left

```
>x = [2,80,99,2,34,57,7,68,9,0,77,19,24]
# i travels from len(x)-1= lst index, 0, -1 steps to be taken
for i in range(len(x)-1,0,-1):
    # here j travels from 0th index to ith index
    for j in range(i):
        if x[j]<x[j+1]:
            x[j+1],x[j] = x[j],x[j+1]
            
print(x)
```

Solution2: Here j travels from left to right

```
> arr = [2,80,99,2,34,57,7,68,9,0,77,19,24]
#start i from last index + 1 in arr, and step down by 1 till 0th index acting as round counter.
for i in range(len(arr),0,-1):
    #start inner loop j that can traverse from last index till length(arr)-i .... 
    # .... with 1 step down every time to limit j from going beyond length(arr)-i towards left of arr.
    for j in range(len(arr)-1,len(arr)-i,-1):
        #check if the left adjacent element is less than current element at j.
        if arr[j-1]<arr[j]:
            #if above condition is true, swap the adjacent element and element at j.
            arr[j], arr[j-1] = arr[j-1], arr[j]

print(arr)
```